# While submitting jar need to provide property file path

Tags: java

My `app.jar` is present at path `/home/user/app/` and my property file location can be changed suppose it is present at location `/home/user/path/appproperty.properties`.

So I want to give property file location while submitting jar.

```
java -jar app.jar -Dappproperty.properties="/home/user/path/appproperty.properties"
```

But I am getting:

> Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: appproperty.properties (No such file or directory)

My code:

```
Properties p = new Properties();
FileInputStream fileStream = new FileInputStream("appproperty.properties");
p.load(fileStream);
System.out.println("_username "+p.getProperty("_username"));
System.out.println("_password "+p.getProperty("_password"));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that by passing `-Dappproperty.properties="..."` to the JVM,
you are expecting that `new FileInputStream("appproperty.properties");` will use its string parameter to find it.
That's *not* how it works.

Parameters passed with `-D` are accessible as system properties,
through `System.getProperty(...)`.
So it seems you're looking for something like this:

```
String path = System.getProperty("appproperty.properties", "");
if (new File(path).isFile()) {
    try (FileInputStream fileStream = new FileInputStream(path)) {
        Properties p = new Properties();
        p.load(fileStream);
        System.out.println("_username "+p.getProperty("_username"));
        System.out.println("_password "+p.getProperty("_password"));
    }
}
```

Finally, very importantly, you need to pass the properties *before* the `-jar` parameter, not after:

```
java -Dappproperty.properties="/home/user/path/appproperty.properties" -jar app.jar
```